# Проблема со сменой цвета (Colorful.Console)

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

Решил по приколу повторить мем с ютуба, использовал библиотеку Colorful.Console,
Код:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var musicThread = new Thread(() => StartMusic("ghoul.mp3"));
            musicThread.Start();

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.Write("Я.", Color.Red);
            Thread.Sleep(1700);
            Console.Write(" Гуль.\n\n", Color.Chartreuse);

            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            var random = new Random();

            for (int i = 1000; i >= 7; i -= 7)
            {
                // todo Первые 10-15 строк с рандомным цветом, остальные с одинаковым.

                int red = random.Next(255);
                int green = random.Next(255);
                int blue = random.Next(255);
                
                Console.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
                
                Console.WriteLine($"{i} - 7 = {i - 7}");

                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        }

        private static void StartMusic(string filename)
        {
            using (var audioFile = new AudioFileReader(filename))
            using (var outputDevice = new WaveOutEvent())
            {
                outputDevice.Init(audioFile);
                outputDevice.Play();

                while (outputDevice.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            }
        }
```

Вначале запускается музыка в отдельном потоке, но я проверил, это ни на что не влияет вообще
Так же точно не влияет генератор случайных чисел, он выдаёт реально случайные числа.
Раньше вместо присваивания нового цвета Console.BackgroundColor, я передавал этот цвет в сам метод вывода, никакой реакции. Если изменять не фоновый цвет, а цвет текста, аналогично, проблема остаётся, но только с цветом самого текста.

Видео с проблемой залил на ютуб, ссылка: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LZ8tXYIJh8

Comment: Так в чем именно проблема то? Как оно должно работать?

Comment: после вывода 10-15 строк, цвет застывает на одном значении, несмотря на то что случайные числа разные, и каждую итерацию цикла он меняется

Comment: Так может это проблема библиотеки, а не вашего кода?

Comment: хз, может быть. Но на гитхабе либы нет issue по этому поводу, пойду сделаю

Comment: Кстати, `var musicThread = new Thread(() => StartMusic("ghoul.mp3"));` замените на просто `Task.Run(() => StartMusic("ghoul.mp3"));`. Тогда приложение при закрытии не будет виснуть в процессах. Либо еще можно так `var musicThread = new Thread(() => StartMusic("ghoul.mp3")) { IsBackground = true };`

Comment: окей, не знал, спасибо

Comment: Попробуйте еще так `Console.BackgroundColor = (ConsoleColor)random.Next(16);` Для такого варианта не потребуется внешних библиотек.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131454/discussion-between-blit-gaming-and-aepot).

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не в коде, а в библиотеке.
К сожалению автор забросил свою библиотеку, судя по коммитам.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).